# How to connect AzureML (Machine Learning) with AzureVM (Virtual Machine)?

Tags: php, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-notebooks

We use AzureML notebook for object detection with ImageAI.
We have a Virtual Machine placed on Azure VM.
It has an IP (say 104.45.19.XXX if needed)

We need to read some files from the folders that are uploaded from mobile apps in this folder on this AzureVM:
C:\inetpub\ftproot\

An example folder is:
C:\inetpub\ftproot\ID1 1565636032150 1 - where long number is miliseconds from 1970 & 1 at the end is a number of pictures.

We tried to connect from AzureML through a button Jupyter => [MENU ITEM] Azure => Connect to Azure => Grant access

Then we get a window with the message:
AADSTS90002: Tenant 'null' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check with your subscription administrator.

1) How can we connect from AzureML notebook to AzureVM because this method should work as we have both: AzureML & AzureVM?

2) [OPTIONAL] How can we then check for a new folder being created please?

Thanks, Eric

Answer (score 0):

I assume you trying to connect a VM to [Azure Notebooks](https://notebooks.azure.com/) (let me know if that is not the case).

IIRC, Azure Notebooks looks for VMs in your subscription that are built from certain marketplace images. I think it is restricted to just Linux images -- in any case, the VM needs to run DockerHub for Azure Notebooks to be able to connect. A [Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux (Ubuntu)](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-en/marketplace/apps/microsoft-dsvm.linux-data-science-vm-ubuntu?tab=Overview) is known to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please find instructions here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notebooks/use-data-science-virtual-machine on how DSVM can work with Azure Notebooks